# Is there a way to detect non-movement (touch events)?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to detect a finger's non-movement by using a combination of UITouch events?
The event methods touchesEnded and touchesCancelled are only fired when the event is cancelled or the finger lifted. I would like to know when a touch has stopped moving, even while it is still touching the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the following `UITouch` property:

```
UITouchPhase phase;
```

if its value is `UITouchPhaseStationary`, then the finger has not moved on the screen since the last event received. This implies that you get the related touch in

```
touchesBegan:withEvent:
```

and then the user simply does not move his/her finger.